# Apache ProxyRequest simple test?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I want to know if the ProxyPass works.

```
ProxyPass  /dontexist.php  http://localhost:8888/allo.html
ProxyPassReverse /dontexist.php http://localhost:8888/allo.html
```

When I do this, it does not return me the content of allo.html but a 404 errors. Does it means that the proxy doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

If the proxy wasn't working you would likely get a `502` response code.

If you set `LogLevel debug` and then review your Apache `error_log`, it will be extremely clear what the behavior is.

You should also verify you can hit the HTTP server on port 8888 and that it responds to /allo.html:

`curl http://localhost:8888/allo.html`

If you get a 200 response, then your proxy is not working (since it returns a 404).

ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse's first argument is a `path`, I have personally never used it given a path inclusive of a filename (but I think I have done it via mod_rewrite using the [P] flag. It may very well be that is your problem.

The typical format I have seen (and used) ProxyPass for specifies paths that do not include filenames, like:

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/`

(perhaps someone else is able to clarify that particular nuance based on experience)